# Unable to inject secret file into podman container using compose method - UID/GID issue

Tags: podman, podman-compose

I am trying to inject a secret file into a container by way of a compose file. After running `podman-compose` the file exists within the container but the UID/GID settings are incorrect and I am unable to access the file.

Here is the testing snippet from my compose file for demonstration:

```
services:
  test-new_app:
    secrets:
      - source: id_rsa_pub
        target: /root/id_rsa.pub
...
secrets:
  id_rsa_pub:
    file: /home/refriedjello/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Once inside the container these are the file stats:

```
app ~ # pwd
/root
app ~ # ls -altr | grep id_rsa.pub
ls: cannot access 'id_rsa.pub': Permission denied
-?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? id_rsa.pub
```

If I try to set the mode/uid/gid values under the `secrets` definition for that service in my compose file `podman-compose` returns this error:

```
WARNING: Service "test-new_app" uses secret "/root/id_rsa.pub" with uid, gid, or mode. These fields are not supported by this implementation of the Compose file
```

Here is the version of podman I am running:

```
$ podman -v
podman version 4.4.1
```

I don't understand the issue. In terms of supported fields for the compose file I am referencing this documentation:

https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md

Comment: considering the underlying key has restricted permissions that might explain the issue with permission denied.   the container is running as a user that is not you or at least appears to not be that user inside the container.   you might try figuring out the gid/uid  that the user is runing as in the container and set matching (by number) info on a copy of your key file and see if that file is usable, just a thought.

Comment: I think you're right and the underlying issue is SELinux context/settings on the source file. I haven't had this issue with other files inside the container, and I confirmed my UID is being mapped to the root user's UID in the container. I have done some research and cannot find a good answer. If I wanted to go this route would I have to copy file, strip/change SELinux context, and then copy file in?